# Trying to typeguard my custom event system in UnityTiny

Tags: typescript, unity-game-engine, generics, ecmascript-5, typeguards

I'm creating an event system in Unity Tiny because the one in the framework itself is very limited. I got it working but now I would like to make it more userfriendly for my colleagues. So I tried to typeguard it to prevent users from using different types but it does not seem to work for me. Any suggestions?

I already looked at these:
- https://medium.com/ovrsea/checking-the-type-of-an-object-in-typescript-the-type-guards-24d98d9119b0
- https://dev.to/krumpet/generic-type-guard-in-typescript-258l

The problem is that unity tiny is using es5. So you can't get the object.construtor.name to get the name of a type. Therefor using "instanceof" isn't possible.

Also, the (object as T) does not work and I could not get the (object as T).type either.

```js
export class Event<T> implements IEvent<T>{
        private handlers: {(data?: T): void}[] = [];
        public type : T;

        constructor(value: T){
            this.type = value;
        }


        public On(handler: { (data?: T): void }) : void {
            this.handlers.push(handler);
        }

        public Off(handler: { (data?: T): void }) : void {
            this.handlers = this.handlers.filter(h => h !== handler);
        }

        public Trigger(data?: T) {
            this.handlers.slice(0).forEach(h => h(data));
        }

        public Expose() : IEvent<T> {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

```js
export class EventUtils {
        public static events = new Object();

        public static CreateEvent<T>(eventEntity: ut.Entity, nameOfEvent: string) : void{
            this.events[nameOfEvent] = new game.Event<T>();
        }

        public static Subscribe<T>(nameOfEvent: string, handeler: {(data? : T): void}) : void{
            //Loop through events object, look for nameOfEvent, use checkEventType() to check if it is the same type as given generic, then subscribe if true.
        }

        public static Trigger<T>(nameOfEvent: string, parameter?: T) : void{
            //Loop through events object, look for nameOfEvent, use checkEventType() to check if it is the same type as given generic, then trigger if true.
        }

        private static checkEventType<T>(object: any) : object is Event<T>{
            let temp : T;
            let temp2 = {temp};

            if (object.type instanceof temp2.constructor.name) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

```js
private static checkEventType<T>(object: any) : object is Event<T>{
            let temp : T;

            if (object.type as typeof temp) {
                return true;
                //always returns true even if the type is different
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and

```
let temp : T;

            if ((object.type as typeof temp).type) {
                return true;
                //property 'type' does not exist in 'T'  
            }
            return false;
```

Comment: *`The problem is that unity tiny is using es5`* Either (a) you are not using Unity3D's Project Tiny, which [uses C#](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.tiny@0.16/manual/scripting-systems.html#creating-a-system) just like the rest of the Unity engine or (b) you aren't using Unity 3D and have mistagged your question. And I'm not sure which. Unity dropped support for JS (correctly, UnityScript) [in 2017](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/08/11/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset/).

Comment: I'm using tiny build 14.5 which uses typescript. Typescript is related to javascripts so it uses some of the same lib's. So yes, I used the correct tags

Comment: Please link me to a webpage regarding the package. I can't find any information about it.

Comment: You need unity build 2018.3 or higher but below 
2019:    
https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/12/05/project-tiny-preview-package-is-here/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instanceof` exists and has been supported for [a while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) so you can use it even in ES5.

The only problem is the way you are doing your check. If you need to check for an instance of a class you need to actually have the class (not just the type) in the `checkEventType` function:

```
public static checkEventType<T>(cls: new (...a: any[]) => T, object: any): object is Event<T> {
    if (object.type instanceof cls) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4FEBuwB2MAPACoB8cAlgLZhLDUEyYCSuTpZA3gFBz9wwUSjhQxgcABYp8AE3pQ0ALjhc4AClliUAfhUkAlCpwRKsuAF8A2gF04AXji2A3HwFgArgCMklBHBgATzBgfVc3fgQIfDQYKA8EGGh1USQPULhDVQiBfhhJSjQAOiCQhzhU9Ndcix463M8fPzgAeXx1aTkFFTVNbT1MowrTcwshkzNs3Nz8wqLO+WBFIs80SQ6ZRagDaoFanMbffxaAMxONrqWejS0YXX1xkctHyd5pgVnihYVMR0-5zY-IonShIcRQDoOCiSOAAQnsjm+Sx2OX2DW8R0ywgA5tiln07gMsm93gECl9AUtimgjsB1AAGAzA6BYFAIdYw+zQgkoAwomr1dwY5pYcAQNB0obsQicKakqDAGAeKD4MmFXb8Wq1UCQWCIVAYbB4QgAVRgoMwJP4h2asTEzWAxuYKgASsAolBZERYsJ8NiADRGjgyQJkCiOLgWcLopr+O3m-wAYQVYmA0uI5HUjqYWEIlCC+kD+BQjFO6ZUPsofoMcGMIyt03+2cIaCsxdLJ3Tdkc+GAAHcgzLM82YLnzUF+XtBdbhXG7gm4ABlbxoBDCLzATjqdvAMtOitxKsBqSbYDdVQ3foPOuTMY38wN3IAeifABkIBAwGSoBAPNiYSOmAQF4ABW7owIGSAfgA1nAJzQHAO57kwgYeBKiCSO60HpiQwSSgEEAYVhVAnFQ8CFGSEhoCWEilBI6BwNiIgEIxBBLH4gb5CxaArmulAbiRATxMARSotOgiznA8bNCQOJ4lAW5IZ2+5SYefqBmAKBQDR4JEi8D45M+b4fl++Q-n+AFOkBoHgZBMFwQhSnpqh6HslhOF4eoNZJERCCwZQpH5lQmBcVJNEBHhcAMUxxqsb2wgIJxmGqoeuJLIJcTpKJAoHJJ0n+G5fkeSEW7IMoiH9hoRTVSgKghrYNZcpkgbAWBiR1fggRDK14HBYOGYUI+AgBRoPWJCUkVVna+AIMAECkWVNZDe8CpKiqQlVIZU6knAq3KqqJwoEgEoapYPD7Mg6CYAAghetwoOUABEj1nTw9DwI68COOmZoWkUybAKm6bbpV11eYGj3XY9KJvYqUkQIwuBff1v3HUUgFWJDj02K4I3qD95po4V2FOrhITqNdgafXycr8J9E0hEU93OHAL4RWUFHXedQA)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have not tested this but it seems logical. I'll post the followup shortly